# R Splitting the column into 2 with out changing other columns

Tags: r, strsplit

I have my input. I am using R. I want solution in R

```
    id       places         present   
   1234    |new|world|life   yes
   5111      
 2012222   |lamp             yes
 123333    |world11|ness     yes
```

I want output

```
      id       places         present   
   1234        new            y9970s
   1234        world          7655s
   1234        life           54644s
   5111      
2012222        lamp           y777s
 123333        world11        y998s
 123333        ness           y99s
```

I have tried

```
dt <- data.table(input)
dt=dt[ , list( V3 = unlist( strsplit(as.character( V3),"\\|") ) ) , by = V1]
```

but the 3rd column is left out. Even if I have multiple columns in that case how will I work

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Someone will help you improve your code if you demonstrate that you made some effort before asking for help on SO.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I have tried     dt <- data.table(input)
dt=dt[ , list( V3 = unlist( strsplit(as.character( V2),"\\|") ) ) , by = V1]
but the other columns are left if I have additional column than present

Comment: @user3619015 did you try the suggested code from my answer?

Comment: can you include a `dput` of (a part of) your data?

Comment: Its giving an additional column for the first pipe which it shudn't.      2012222        lamp           y777s                              2012222                       y777s

Comment: I dont know about dput what does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution with the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
new.dt <- dt[,strsplit(as.character(places),"|",fixed=TRUE), by=list(id,present)]
```

Comment: there is an empty column because of the first pipe symbol and it should not come. First Id element 1234 has 4 rows, but it should give 3 rows